# Have you ever seen this kind of "Logarithmic" Volterra integral equations?

Tags: integral-equations

I am currently trying to solve a set of integral equations of the form

\begin{equation}
\ln \int^1_0 f(s, t) \ \text{d}s = b + \int_0^1 w(t, s) \ \ln f(t, s) \ \text{d}s,
\end{equation}

where $b \in \mathbb{R}$, for $f$ in the set of 1-periodic functions, $[0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ with $f(s, t) = f(s, t + 1) = f(s + 1, t)$.

I am reading Masujima's *Applied Mathematical Methods of Theoretical Physics* but could not find a solution to this class of equations. Do you know of any solution to these or can you point me to some paper/book that my work on similar problems?

Thank you!